# How to avoid Query doubles INSERT into database?

Tags: php, mysql, database

**Problem:**
I have made a simple form that uses PHP to pass information to my database via a INSERT query. However, every time I run it, it tries to put the information in twice. How can I avoid this?

**Explanation:**
I first insert the answers, into my answers table, save the AnswerID as a variable. Then do the save with my question table and lastly I use the two saved variables containing the ID's into my question_answers table.

**My code:**

```
if (isset($_POST['textinput1']) && !empty($_POST['textinput1'])) {

      $text1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['textinput1']);
      $text2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['textinput2']);
      $q_text = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['textarea']);

      $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO answers (Answer1Text, Answer2Text) VALUES (?, ?)");
      $stmt->bind_param('ss', $text1, $text2);
      $stmt->execute();
      $answerid = $stmt->insert_id;
      $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO question (QuestionText) VALUES (?)");
      $stmt->bind_param('s', $q_text);
      $stmt->execute();
      $questionid = $stmt->insert_id;
      if ($stmt->execute()) {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO question_answers (AnswerID, QuestionID) VALUES (?, ?)");
        $stmt->bind_param('ss', $answerid, $questionid);
        $stmt->execute();
        echo "<h2>Dit spørgsmål er nu lagt op på siden!</h2>";
        echo "<h3>Tusinde tak for din interesse for SMIL - Skodfri Århus.</h3>";
      }
      else
      {
        echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute . " . mysqli_error($conn);
      }
    }

    // close connection
    mysqli_close($conn);
    ?>
```

**My tables of importance:**
**question:** QuestionID(PK), QuestionText
**answers:** AnswerID(PK), Answer1Text, Answer2Text
**question_answers:** QuestionAnswerID(PK), QuestionID(FK), AnswerID(FK)

Ps. I prefer not to use *composite unique constraint* as a solution.

Also a side-question, should `$stmt->insert_id` variables be `mysqli_real_escape_string`?

Comment: Are all the tables having data inserted twice?

Comment: You run `$stmt->execute()` twice. With prepared statements you don't need to be escaping.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that was indeed the problem. Ah, does that mean this code is safe against SQL injections as it is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you have executed the second query TWICE

```
if (isset($_POST['textinput1']) && !empty($_POST['textinput1'])) {

      $text1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['textinput1']);
      $text2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['textinput2']);
      $q_text = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['textarea']);

      $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO answers (Answer1Text, Answer2Text) VALUES (?, ?)");
      $stmt->bind_param('ss', $text1, $text2);
      $stmt->execute();
      $answerid = $stmt->insert_id;
      $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO question (QuestionText) VALUES (?)");
      $stmt->bind_param('s', $q_text);
      $stmt->execute();
      $questionid = $stmt->insert_id;

      // THIS IS THE SECOND EXECUTION OF QUERY 2
      if ($stmt->execute()) {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO question_answers (AnswerID, QuestionID) VALUES (?, ?)");
        $stmt->bind_param('ss', $answerid, $questionid);
        $stmt->execute();
        echo "<h2>Dit spørgsmål er nu lagt op på siden!</h2>";
        echo "<h3>Tusinde tak for din interesse for SMIL - Skodfri Århus.</h3>";
      }
      else
      {
        echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute . " . mysqli_error($conn);
      }
    }

    // close connection
    mysqli_close($conn);
    ?>
```

Instead try this as the IF test

```
    //if ($stmt->execute()) {
    if ( isset($answerid,$questionid) ) {
```

Comment: By defining my queries as '$stmt1' and '$stmt2' and then as safety, having a 'if ( isset($answerid,$questionid) ) {' helped solve the problem. Thanks so much for all the answers.

Answer (score 1):

`if ($stmt->execute()) {`

this runs one of your statements a second time. You should assign the return value to a variable if you need it for something later.